# unknown log files IIS creates

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, log-files

I have a question:

I'm working on a project in C # that creates log files in my local computer creates the necessary files and writes perfectly.

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("mylog.log"), "myListener"));
Trace.TraceInformation( "test message");
Trace.Flush();
```

But in my server also creates other files with unknown names like this:

62735167-1d87-4521-a1f2-40504fb51b59mylog.log

and contains the following lines I write.
I can not delete that file.
Any solution for this problem?

thanks

Comment: You probably can't delete that file because some process has a lock on it.  Run Process Explorer to see which process has a file handle for the file.  That would be the first step to figuring out what's going on.

Comment: my problem is: why write the line in another file?

Comment: You probably have a default trace listener. The log file name itself looks like it might have been derived from a call to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.